# Spark: Jobs are not assigned

Tags: apache-spark

I've deployed an spark cluster into my kubernetes. Here webui:

[image]

I'm trying to submit an sark SparkPi example using:

```
$ ./spark-submit \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
  --master spark://spark-cluster-ra-iot-dev.si-origin-cluster.t-systems.es:32316 \
  --num-executors 1 \
  --driver-memory 512m \
  --executor-memory 512m \
  --executor-cores 1 \
  ../examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.5.jar 10
```

Job is reached on spark cluster:

[image]

Nevertheless, I'm getting messages like:

> WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

I seems like `SparkPi` application is scheduled but never executed...

Here complete log:

```
./spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master spark://spark-cluster-ra-iot-dev.si-origin-cluster.t-systems.es:32316 --num-executors 1 --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m --executor-cores 1 ../examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.5.jar 10
20/06/09 10:52:57 WARN Utils: Your hostname, psgd resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.0.2.15 instead (on interface enp0s3)
20/06/09 10:52:57 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
20/06/09 10:52:57 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
20/06/09 10:52:58 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.5
20/06/09 10:52:58 INFO SparkContext: Submitted application: Spark Pi
20/06/09 10:52:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: jeusdi
20/06/09 10:52:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: jeusdi
20/06/09 10:52:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
20/06/09 10:52:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
20/06/09 10:52:58 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(jeusdi); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(jeusdi); groups with modify permissions: Set()
20/06/09 10:52:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 42943.
20/06/09 10:52:59 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
20/06/09 10:52:59 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
20/06/09 10:52:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
20/06/09 10:52:59 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
20/06/09 10:52:59 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-b6c54054-c94b-42c7-b85f-a4e30be4b659
20/06/09 10:52:59 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 117.0 MB
20/06/09 10:52:59 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
20/06/09 10:52:59 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
20/06/09 10:53:00 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://10.0.2.15:4040
20/06/09 10:53:00 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/valladolid/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/../examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.5.jar at spark://10.0.2.15:42943/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.4.5.jar with timestamp 1591692780146
20/06/09 10:53:00 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Connecting to master spark://spark-cluster-ra-iot-dev.si-origin-cluster.t-systems.es:32316...
20/06/09 10:53:00 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to spark-cluster-ra-iot-dev.si-origin-cluster.t-systems.es/10.49.160.69:32316 after 152 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Connected to Spark cluster with app ID app-20200609085300-0002
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/0 on worker-20200609084543-10.129.3.127-45867 (10.129.3.127:45867) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/0 on hostPort 10.129.3.127:45867 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/1 on worker-20200609084543-10.129.3.127-45867 (10.129.3.127:45867) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/1 on hostPort 10.129.3.127:45867 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/2 on worker-20200609084543-10.129.3.127-45867 (10.129.3.127:45867) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/2 on hostPort 10.129.3.127:45867 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/3 on worker-20200609084543-10.129.3.127-45867 (10.129.3.127:45867) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/3 on hostPort 10.129.3.127:45867 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/4 on worker-20200609084543-10.129.3.127-45867 (10.129.3.127:45867) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/4 on hostPort 10.129.3.127:45867 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 33755.
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 10.0.2.15:33755
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/5 on worker-20200609084509-10.128.3.197-41600 (10.128.3.197:41600) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/5 on hostPort 10.128.3.197:41600 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/6 on worker-20200609084509-10.128.3.197-41600 (10.128.3.197:41600) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/6 on hostPort 10.128.3.197:41600 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/7 on worker-20200609084509-10.128.3.197-41600 (10.128.3.197:41600) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/7 on hostPort 10.128.3.197:41600 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/8 on worker-20200609084509-10.128.3.197-41600 (10.128.3.197:41600) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/8 on hostPort 10.128.3.197:41600 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/9 on worker-20200609084509-10.128.3.197-41600 (10.128.3.197:41600) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/9 on hostPort 10.128.3.197:41600 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/10 on worker-20200609084426-10.131.1.27-46041 (10.131.1.27:46041) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/10 on hostPort 10.131.1.27:46041 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/11 on worker-20200609084426-10.131.1.27-46041 (10.131.1.27:46041) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/11 on hostPort 10.131.1.27:46041 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/12 on worker-20200609084426-10.131.1.27-46041 (10.131.1.27:46041) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/12 on hostPort 10.131.1.27:46041 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/13 on worker-20200609084426-10.131.1.27-46041 (10.131.1.27:46041) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/13 on hostPort 10.131.1.27:46041 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/14 on worker-20200609084426-10.131.1.27-46041 (10.131.1.27:46041) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/14 on hostPort 10.131.1.27:46041 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/5 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/6 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/7 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/8 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 33755, None)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/9 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager 10.0.2.15:33755 with 117.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 33755, None)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/10 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/11 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 33755, None)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(driver, 10.0.2.15, 33755, None)
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/12 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/13 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/14 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/0 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/1 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/2 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/3 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/4 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:53:01 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.0
20/06/09 10:53:02 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: reduce at SparkPi.scala:38
20/06/09 10:53:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (reduce at SparkPi.scala:38) with 10 output partitions
20/06/09 10:53:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (reduce at SparkPi.scala:38)
20/06/09 10:53:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
20/06/09 10:53:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
20/06/09 10:53:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at SparkPi.scala:34), which has no missing parents
20/06/09 10:53:03 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.0 KB, free 117.0 MB)
20/06/09 10:53:03 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1381.0 B, free 117.0 MB)
20/06/09 10:53:03 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.0.2.15:33755 (size: 1381.0 B, free: 117.0 MB)
20/06/09 10:53:03 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1163
20/06/09 10:53:03 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 10 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at SparkPi.scala:34) (first 15 tasks are for partitions Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
20/06/09 10:53:03 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 10 tasks
20/06/09 10:53:18 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
20/06/09 10:53:33 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
20/06/09 10:53:48 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
20/06/09 10:54:03 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
20/06/09 10:54:18 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
20/06/09 10:54:33 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
20/06/09 10:54:48 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/13 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20200609085300-0002/13 removed: Command exited with code 1
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/15 on worker-20200609084426-10.131.1.27-46041 (10.131.1.27:46041) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/15 on hostPort 10.131.1.27:46041 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 13 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 13 requested
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 13
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/15 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:55:03 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/12 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20200609085300-0002/12 removed: Command exited with code 1
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 12 requested
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 12
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 12 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/16 on worker-20200609084426-10.131.1.27-46041 (10.131.1.27:46041) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/16 on hostPort 10.131.1.27:46041 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/16 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/14 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20200609085300-0002/14 removed: Command exited with code 1
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 14 requested
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 14
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 14 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/17 on worker-20200609084426-10.131.1.27-46041 (10.131.1.27:46041) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/17 on hostPort 10.131.1.27:46041 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/17 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/10 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20200609085300-0002/10 removed: Command exited with code 1
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 10 requested
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 10
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 10 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/18 on worker-20200609084426-10.131.1.27-46041 (10.131.1.27:46041) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/18 on hostPort 10.131.1.27:46041 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/18 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/8 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20200609085300-0002/8 removed: Command exited with code 1
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 8 requested
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 8
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 8 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/19 on worker-20200609084509-10.128.3.197-41600 (10.128.3.197:41600) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/19 on hostPort 10.128.3.197:41600 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/11 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20200609085300-0002/11 removed: Command exited with code 1
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 11 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 11 requested
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 11
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/20 on worker-20200609084426-10.131.1.27-46041 (10.131.1.27:46041) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/20 on hostPort 10.131.1.27:46041 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/19 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/20 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/7 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20200609085300-0002/7 removed: Command exited with code 1
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 7 requested
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 7
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 7 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/21 on worker-20200609084509-10.128.3.197-41600 (10.128.3.197:41600) with 1 core(s)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Granted executor ID app-20200609085300-0002/21 on hostPort 10.128.3.197:41600 with 1 core(s), 512.0 MB RAM
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/21 is now RUNNING
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor updated: app-20200609085300-0002/9 is now EXITED (Command exited with code 1)
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneSchedulerBackend: Executor app-20200609085300-0002/9 removed: Command exited with code 1
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Removal of executor 9 requested
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint: Asked to remove non-existent executor 9
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Trying to remove executor 9 from BlockManagerMaster.
20/06/09 10:55:03 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor added: app-20200609085300-0002/22 on worker-20200609084509-10.128.3.197-41600 (10.128.3.197:41600) with 1 core(s)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Make sure that correct ports on the master node and worker nodes are opened.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#configuring-ports-for-network-security

Alternatively, drop the firewall completely on master and worker node(s), although that is not recommended.